# Wagtail and Django-Tenants, does it work together?

Tags: django, compatibility, multi-tenant, wagtail

Does anyone have experience in this topic? Is it fully incompatible or might it be possible to customize certain parts of the app to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

`multi-tenancy` is not yet fully supported by Wagtail.
Although, as [mentioned here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/multi_site_multi_instance_multi_tenancy.html#multi-tenancy) in docs, there are some features that are supported.

You may find [this blog](https://wagtail.io/blog/multi-site-wagtail/) helpful. Also [here is a repository](https://github.com/chrxr/multi-site-wagtail) that implements basic features of multi tenancy with django and wagtail and you can play around with it.

Here are [some other CMS](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/django-cms/) (build on top of Django) you can try.

Comment: If someone have worked with `wagtail` + `django` + `django-tenants` or have find any example consist of these packages please share it though.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better. Also, provide a basic coverage of the content of your link, in case it stops working in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as there are no raw sql queries in wagtail's source code we are good to use [django-tenents](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants), the layer that django-tenets is working on is on top of django orm it self.

see [wagtail-tenents](https://github.com/borisbrue/wagtail-tenants)